# Which Third Party Components Have You Installed Into Delphi And Why?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Which third party components have you installed into Dephi and why?

I'm moving from D5 Enterprise to Delphi 2010. I haven't installed 3rd party tools in the past but I did upgrade to QReports Pro and TChart Pro.

I will writing database apps so lots of inserts, updates & deletes will be going on. Database queries, searches and filtering with be happening along with reporting. I also want to provide PDF output as a printing option.

I'd like to hear from you what tools you like, which tools use and why.

Comment: This is subjective, and there can't be a definite answer. There are already questions about good components. Regarding you last sentence: SO is neither a forum nor a chat room.

Comment: I would allow this question if it were community wiki.

Comment: which ones do you have installed on Delphi 5 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regularly use the following:

- [Toolbar2000](http://jrsoftware.org) by Jordan Russel
- [PascalScript](http://www.remobjects.com) by RemObjects
- [IBObjects](http://www.ibobjects.com) by Jason Wharton
- [SynEdit](http://synedit.sourceforge.net) on sourceforge
- [Raize Components](http://www.raize.com) by Ray Konopka
- [DCPcrypt](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/cryptography.html) by Dave Barton
- [HTMLViewer](http://htmlviewer.sourceforge.net/) originally by Dave Baldwin now on sourceforge
- [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com) by Fabio Dell'Aria

I have a number of others, but these seem to be used a lot for different things.

Ryan.

Answer (score 2):

Have a good look at [RemObjects DataAbstract](http://www.dataabstract.com/). It adds great database independence and interoperability and a good business logic layer.

Answer (score 2):

TMS Software, pretty much everything they have written, and the only reason, it add style that D2009 is still missing in part. They are not the best controls in the world but they are reasonably bug free.

FIB Plus for access to Firebird, just a very nice set of components for the task.

and several other one off components that I use regularly or have sub classed for one reason or another.

RE

Comment: +1 for TMS. Somewhat expensive, but worth every penny and support is excellent

Answer (score 1):

[Zeos](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) for Database Access. It supports a lot of DB types including sqlite, mysql, postgres.

Answer (score 1):

- [Fast Report](http://ns.fast-report.com/en/products/report-generator-for-delphi-fastreport-4.html) for Reporting
- [FastScript](http://ns.fast-report.com/en/products/fast-script.html) for scripting
- [Toolbar2000](http://www.jrsoftware.org/tb2k.php), Tbx, [SpTbx](http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/index.htm), various themable components
- DevExpress for Grid
- Jvcl for some visual and non visual components
- [NexusDB](http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=nexusdb) for embedded client side database
- Lockbox for crypt
- Abbrevia for compression
- [XDom](http://www.philo.de/xml/) (OpenXml)
- DxSock (defunc) for Socket Server

and some home made

Answer (score 1):

First add DevExpress VCL (QuantumGrid and the editors it comes with), the TMS Component Pack and Report Builder.

Then download the latest AsyncPro, and if Indy wasn't already in the box, then add Indy in there too.

That little lot gives you one hell of a Delphi arsenal :-)